# Doctrine - Database type sysname

Tags: doctrine

When a database type not recognised by Doctrine (sysname in my case), how i can force Doctrine at accepted that ?
Type sysname is an equivalent at varchar type but Doctrine doesnt supported  ... and i can't change type of my table.

Maybe a solution with install a driver or maybe like that ?

For information, my database is an SQL Server 2005 and command for generate ORM is :

php app/console doctrine:mapping:import MyBundle yml

And when i trying --filter="TableName" it don't work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Doctrine, if it is varcahr type simply do like below in your model class:

Assuming table fieldname is FirstName

```
/**
 * @var string $firstName
 * @Column(name="FirstName", type="string", length=60, nullable=false)
 */
protected $firstName;


/**
 * Set the first name
 *
 * @param $firstName
 * @return string
 */
public function setFirstName($firstName)
{
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get the first name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->firstName;
}
```

Comment: I haven't model class, my database is import with doctrine command and after that, the model class is created.
Maybe it's bad process ?

In order : 
- Configure connection at database (host,dbname etc.)
- Launch command with php app/console
- Model class created 

It's not like that ?

Comment: Here is the way to generate models automatically:


<?php

// Include main doctrine calss

        require_once('Doctrine.php');

spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));

// Create Doctrine manager

$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();

// Create DB connection

$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection('mysql://USER:PASSWORD@localhost/DATABASE', 'doctrine');

// Auto-generate models

Doctrine::generateModelsFromDb(

'tmp/models', 

array('doctrine'), 

array('classPrefix' =>'PROJECT_Model_', 'classPrefixFiles' => false)

);

    ?>